# How Do I Replicate Current Grub2 Install?

Tags: arch-linux, windows, grub2, dual-boot

I've installed Linux in the past alongside Windows 8.1, and I've had problems. I tried several times until I got Grub2 to be installed correctly and display Linux and Windows 8.

My Linux Mint Debian Edition now broke. I want to install Arch Linux (Antergos, specifically) but I don't know where to put Grub2 installer. I want to know which partition Grub2 is now installed on so I can install Grub2 on the same location, since it works correctly.

Comment: Before you do that, why is Mint broken?

Comment: @eyoung100, Installed updates and, from my reading, AMD graphics card drivers broke, I need to reinstall them but it's impossible. I can't see anything in the UI. Everything is dark grey with no way to see what I'm typing in terminal, where I'm navigating in Nemo or anything related to the Cinnamon Desktop UI. It's all indiscernible. Though when I launch a program like Chrome, I can see the app UI correctly (I only can launch Chrome, VirtualBox and VLC since those are the only application I know where to click to get them to launch. They are pinned in the taskbar, which is also indiscernible.)

Comment: Use ctrl +alt + f3 for a terminal

Comment: @eyoung100 I already had a custom shortcut for terminal. The problem is that I can't see the input or output of terminal either. It's all just a grey blob. Though I can get into recovery mode from Grub2 loader, and I can work things out from there. But I just want to learn another linux distro. I think I've spent good amount of time with a Debian-based system.

Comment: No Ctrl + Alt + F3 will take you to a text Terminal